# If we can do functional programming with Python, do we need a specific functional programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, python, functional-programming

Using generators and lambda, we can do functional programming with Python. You can also achieve the same thing with Ruby.

So the question is: why do we need specific functional programming languages such as Erlang, Haskell, and Scheme? Is there anything different that these specific functional programming languages provide? Why can't we just use Python for functional programming?

Comment: all of those were around even before python was created

Comment: A ford Pinto is a car. Why do we need specific fast cars like Ferraris?

Comment: Is python Lambda a true Lambda yet? Last time I checked, it would only accept an expression, not an anonymous function block.

Comment: Using classes and templates, we can do anything OO in C++. Why Java and Python were ever created? What do they add?

Comment: @9000: Well Java added the JVM, which is arguably one of the best language additions ever.

Comment: If Scheme has built-in procedures, why do we need a specific procedural programming language? If we can define objects in Haskell, why do we need a specific object-oriented language?

Comment: All programming languages (sans some purely academic research languages) are Turing equivalent, so what you can do in language A you can do in any other language. So, following this train of thought, we only need one Turing complete language -- say like sendmail.cf ;)  http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/#sendmail-Turing

Comment: If you knew any of these languages, you wouldn't claim that Python does functional programming well. It doesn't. It does it well enough to incorporate a share of FP-ish things, but not any better.

Comment: Lambda in python is a joke. Expressions only, no statements. Needless to mention that expressions and statements are different things in python, which itself makes it a horrible language for functional programming, even if it had a proper lambda.

Comment: @Maglob, I invite you to write a Lisp interpreter in sendmail.cf...

Comment: Please check the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) and [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective) blog post to learn what makes a good question. If you have a specific question to ask please ask that instead.

Comment: It almost seems like we should use Python for everything based on these questions because it does a at least a poor job at everything (although it does a good job at some things, Functional Programming not being one them)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I appreciate the question, because I'm personally a huge fan of both Python and functional style of programming. I have a long background in Python and I have started learning Haskell recently, so here's some points based on my personal experiences on the differences between these too languages, from a functional perspective.

**Purity**

Even if you don't care about the purity of functions (i.e. not having side effects) as a princible, it does have practical effect on how easy it is to read code and reason about it. Even if you maintain purity in your own Python functions, there is a big difference in having the compiler enforce purity and, most of all, having the standard library built on terms of purity and immutable data structures.

**Performance**

You may or may not care about performance depending on what your application domain is, but static typing and guaranteed purity gives the compiler a lot more to work with, compared to Python and other dynamic languages (although I have to admit that PyPy is making great inroads, and e.g. LuaJIT is bordering on miraculous).

**Tail-call Optimization**

Related to performance, but slightly different. Even if you don't care too much about runtime performance, not having tail-call optimization (especially for tail-recursion) limits the ways you can implement algorithms in Python without hitting stack limits.

**Syntax**

This is the biggest reason why I started to look at "real" functional languages instead of just using Python with functional style. Although I think that Python has a very expressive syntax in general, it has some weak spots specific to functional coding. For example:

- Syntax for lambda functions is rather verbose and limited in what they can contain
- No syntactic sugar for function composition i.e. `f = g . h` vs. `f = lambda *arg: g(h(*arg))`
- No syntactic sugar for partial application i.e. `f = map g` vs. `f = functools.partial(map, g)`
- No syntactic sugar for using infix operators in higher order functions i.e. `sum = reduce (+) lst` vs. `sum = reduce(operator.add, lst)`
- No pattern matching or guards for function arguments, which make it easy to express recursion end conditions and some border cases with very readable syntax.
- Brackets are never optional for function calls, and there's no syntactic sugar for nested calls. I guess this is a matter of taste, but especially in functional code, I find it's common to chain function calls and I find `y = func1 $ func2 $ func3 x` easier to read than `y = func1(func2(func3(x)))`, once you are familiar with that notation.

Answer (score 29):

These are the most important differences:

**Haskell**

- Lazy evaluation
- Compiles to machine code
- Static typing ensures functions are pure
- Type inference

**Haskell and Erlang**

- Pattern matching

**Erlang**

- Actor model of concurrency, light-weight processes

**Scheme**

- Macros

**All languages**

- real closures (ruby has closures, whether python does can be debated, see the comments)
- a standard library suitable for a functional programming style (immutable collections, map, filter, fold etc)
- tail recursion (this can be found in some non-functional languages too)

Also, you should have a look at languages from the ML family like SML, Ocaml and F# and Scala, which fuses OO and functional programming in a new way. All these languages have unique interesting features.

Comment: +1 good post. You could add type-inference on Haskell and Light-weight processes on Erlang.

Comment: @Jonas: Thanks for the suggestions, I added them to the answer.

Comment: Python does have map, filter and fold (reduce). Regarding "real closures": If you define a real closure as a closure which can contain something other than a single expression, Haskell doesn't have real closures either (but of course Haskell has few things that aren't expressions...). However the point about immutable data structures is a good one, so +1 for that. Also: tail recursion (and generally less expensive recursion).

Comment: +1 for "static typing ensures functions are pure". It's very cool to have a type system that discriminates between pure and non-pure functions. (C++'s const doe snot count. :)

Comment: To the features that Scheme provides, you can add first class continuations, which allow the programmer to define new control flow constructs.

Comment: @corriganjc: Ruby has continuations, too. Also, I wouldn't consider continuation to be a functional programming feature.

Comment: FYI, @hack-saw is wrong, Python has real closures.  Inside of a function you can insert another def, and it will be a true closure that can be as complex as you want.  Be aware, though, that if you want to modify a closed over variable, you need to make it a mutable data type, because assigning to it creates a new variable with a smaller scope.

Comment: @btilly: I wouldn't consider it a closure if you can't assign to a variable that is in scope. Otherwise we'd have to say that Java has closures too, since you can use the same trick there.

Comment: @Kim: Java inner classes are syntactically a lot heavier.  All functions in Python are unable to assign to variables defined outside the function.  It is trivial to get around this restriction in practice, just use a mutable data structure like an array or dictionary.  Furthermore pure functional languages, including Haskell and Erlang, have far stronger assignment restrictions.  If you don't count Python as having closures because of this, then Haskell and Erlang don't have them either!

Comment: In a closure I can access a variable in the same ways I normally can. This is true of Haskell's and Ruby's closures, but not of Python's or Java's poor substitutes. Maybe someone else can enlight us about erlang, I don't know it that well.

Comment: @Kim: In a Python closure you can access a variable in all the same ways that you can in any other function.  I can translate any Ruby code using closures into equivalent Python code, and the result is typically only slightly longer.  (And that mostly because Ruby lets certain short constructs be inline that Python forces you to indent.)  I have to emphatically disagree about how poor a substitute Python's closures are.

Comment: i guess i will have to make some python experiments...

Answer (score 19):

It's hard to define exactly what a "functional language" is--out of the languages you listed, only Haskell is purely functional (all the others adopt some sort of hybrid approach).  There are certain language features that are very helpful for functional programming, though, and Ruby and Python don't have enough of them to be very good environments for FP.  Here is my personal checklist, in order of importance:

1. [First-class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) and [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) (Ruby, Python, and all the others you listed have this).
2. Guaranteed [tail-call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (Erlang, Haskell, Scala, and Scheme have this, but not Python, Ruby, or Clojure (yet)).
3. Support for [immutability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) in the language and standard libraries (this is a big one that all of the "functional languages" you listed have (except Scheme) but Ruby and Python don't).
4. Language-level support for [referentially transparent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science)) (or pure) functions (as far as I know, only Haskell has this currently).

The need for (1) should be obvious--higher-order functions are extremely difficult without first-class functions.  When people talk about Ruby and Python being good languages for FP, they are usually talking about this.  However, this particular feature is necessary but not sufficient to make a language good for FP.

(2) has been a traditional necessity for FP ever since Scheme was invented.  Without TCO, it is impossible to program with deep recursion, which is one of the cornerstones of FP, because you get stack overflows.  The only "functional" (by popular definition) language that doesn't have this is Clojure (because of limitations of the JVM), but Clojure has a variety of hacks to simulate TCO.  (FYI, [Ruby TCO is implementation-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824562/does-ruby-perform-tail-call-optimization), but Python [specifically does not support it](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/final-words-on-tail-calls.html).)  The reason TCO has to be guaranteed is that if it is implementation-specific, deep recursive functions will break with some implementations, so you can't really use them at all.

(3) is another big thing that modern functional languages (especially Haskell, Erlang, Clojure, and Scala) have that Ruby and Python don't.  Without going into too much detail, guaranteed immutability eliminates whole classes of bugs, especially in concurrent situations, and allows for neat things like [persistent data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure).  It's very difficult to take advantage of these benefits without language-level support.

(4) is, for me, the most interesting thing about purely-functional languages (as opposed to hybrid languages).  Consider the following extremely simple Ruby function:

```
def add(a, b)
  a + b
end
```

This looks like a pure function, but because of operator overloading, it could mutate either parameter or cause side effects such as printing to the console.  It's unlikely that someone would overload the `+` operator to have a side effect, but the language gives no guarantees.  (The same applies to Python, although maybe not with this specific example.)

In a purely functional language, on the other hand, there are language-level guarantees that functions are referentially transparent.  This has numerous advantages: pure functions can be easily memoized; they can be easily tested without relying on any sort of global state; and values within the function can be evaluated lazily or in parallel without worrying about concurrency issues.  Haskell takes full advantage of this, but I don't know enough about other functional languages to know if they do.

All that being said, it's possible to use FP techniques in almost any language (even Java). For instance, Google's [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) is inspired by functional ideas, but as far as I know they don't use any "functional" languages for their large projects (I think they mostly use C++, Java, and Python).

Comment: +1 for the thorough explanation - even I as a FP outsider understood it. Thanks! :-)

Comment: most valuable answer to this question so far. Founded on facts and lots of information. Great job.

Comment: Scala has tail recursion and, as with Scheme, it's  done automatically if a recursive call is in tail position (unlike Clojure where it has to be explicitly requested).  There's even an annotation so you can check that the compiler *will* generate tail recursive code.  What it doesn't have is Scheme's more generalised TCO.   I assume you know that but since you went into so much detail about most other things, that seemed an odd dismissal/omission.

Comment: @itsbruce This post is pretty old, IIRC Scala didn't have it at the time (or I may have just been wrong ;). Updated.

Comment: I haven't been using Scala since the beginning but it did have tail recursion in 2008, when I was getting interested ;-)  I refer people who ask about this topic to this particular SO question because it has some good answers and I only just noticed that oddity, so commented for completeness.

Answer (score 11):

The languages you mention are very different.

While Python and Ruby is dynamically typed languages, Haskell is statically typed. Erlang is a concurrent language and uses the Actor model and is very different from all other languages you mention.

Python and Ruby has many imperative constructs while in a more pure functional language like Haskell, everything returns something or in other words everything is a function.

Comment: @kRON: Well, the type system is an important property of a language, and he asked "Is there anything different that these specific functional programming languages provides?". Sure, you can use the Actor model with other languages but Erlang has it built-in in the language. Erlang uses lightweight processes and has built-in language constructs for distributed programming - thence a "concurrent" language.

Answer (score 9):

Late to the party as usual, but going to say things anyway.

A functional programming language isn't a language that **permits** functional programming.  If we were to go by that definition, then pretty much any language anywhere is a functional programming language.  (The same applies to OOP, incidentally.  You can write in an OOP style in C if you like.  Thus, according to your logic, C is an OOP language.)

What makes a functional programming language isn't what it **permits** you to program like, it's what it lets you program like ***easily***.  That's the key.

So, Python has lambdas (which are incredibly anaemic closure-like affairs) and gives you a couple of library functions that you'll see in functional libraries as well like "map" and "fold".  This is not enough to make it a functional programming language, however, because it is difficult to impossible to consistently program in a proper functional *style* in it (and the language **certainly** doesn't enforce this style!).  At its core Python is an imperative language concerned with state and state manipulation operations and this is simply at odds with the expression and expression evaluation semantics of a functional language.

So why do we have functional programming languages when Python (or Ruby (or insert the language of your choice)) can "do functional programming"?  Because Python, et al can't do proper functional programming.  That's why.

Answer (score 6):

You *can* do functional programming in Java (see e.g. http://functionaljava.org/). You can also do [object oriented programming in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c). It's just not that idiomatic.

So indeed we don't *absolutely* need Erlang, Haskell, Scheme, or any specific programming language, but they all represent different approaches and different trade-offs, making some tasks easier and some harder. What you should use depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

This question can be applied to an infinite number of languages and paradigms.

- Since everyone uses C++, why do we need any other general purpose languages?
- Since java is such a great OO language, why do other OO languages exist?
- Since perl is an amazing scripting language, why do we need python?
- Yatta, yatta, yatta

Most, if not all languages exists for a specific reason.  They exist because someone had a need that no current language filled, or filled poorly.  (This of course doesn't apply to every language, but I feel it applies to most of the well known languages.)  For example, python was originally developed to interface with the Amoeba OS [[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#History),[2](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/01/personal-history-part-1-cwi.html)] and Erlang was created to help in the development of telephony applications [[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29#History)].  So one answer to the question "Why do we need another functional language?" can simply be, because [insert-name-of-someone-who-knows-how-to-design-languages] didn't like the way python did it.

That pretty much sums up what I think the answer is.  While you can do anything with python that you can do with a functional language, would you really want to?  Everything you can do in C, you can do in assembly, but would you want to?  Different languages will always be best at doing different things, and that's the way it should be.

Answer (score 3):

Functional programming is as much about a design paradigm as it is about specific language features. Or, put another way, lambdas and a map function do not a functional programming language make. Python and Ruby have some features inspired by functional programming languages, but you still generally write code in a very imperative fashion. (It's sort of like C: you can write OO-like code in C, but no one seriously considers C to be an OO language.)

Look: functional programming is not just about lambdas, or `map`, or higher-order functions. It's about *design*. A program written in a "true" functional programming language solves problems via the composition of functions. While programs written in Ruby or Python may use FP-like features, they generally don't read like a set of composed functions.

Answer (score 0):

Each functional language you mentioned fits into a certain niche quite well and the idiomatic patterns that each encourages makes them very well suited for certain tasks that would be impossible to accomplish in Python unless you built a huge library of helper modules. The most obvious of one such niche excellence is Erlang's model of concurrency. The other ones also have similar strengths.

Answer (score 0):

Every concept available in lambda-calculus, LISP, and Scheme is available in Python, so, yes, you can do functional programming in it. If it's convenient or not is a matter of context and taste.

You can easily write a LISP (or other functional language) interpreter in Python (Ruby, Scala) (what does that amount to?). You can write an interpreter for Python using purely functional, but it would take a lot of work. Even *"functional"* languages are multi-paradigm nowadays.

[This old and beautiful book](http://goo.gl/EM4l3) has most of (though not all) the answers about what the essence of functional programming is.

Comment: @Arkaaito But do you agree that *every concept available in lambda calculus, LISP, and Scheme* is available in Python?

Comment: Are you sure that *every* lisp concept is available in Python? Macros, code-is-data?

Comment: @SK-logic Macros are not in lambda-calculus, but yes, they are available in Python, though not by that name. Python provides an `eval()` function, which is that's needed for __code is data__, but it goes further: it lets you modify most of the runtime environment, like in LISP.

Comment: @Apalala, dynamic languages `eval()` is a runtime metaprogramming. Sometimes it is useful, but it is extremely expensive. Lisp macros are different, it is a compile time metaprogramming. It is not available in Python in any usable form.

Comment: @SK-logic That kind of macros break the _code-is-data_ premise, as programs can't change macros (or even know of their existence). In Python, programs have access to their own parse trees at runtime, if they need them. Macros (static pre-processing) is not functional at all.

Comment: @Apalala, what do you mean by "programs can't change macros"? Of course they can. Homoiconic property is still held, no matter how much of your Lisp system is implemented on top of macros. And, *surprise*, there is an `(eval ...)` in Lisp too.

Comment: @Apalala, I guess you're thinking of Lisp as of a functional language. It is not correct. Lisp is a language with compile time macros, and this property is a way much more important than its limited functional features. And, of course, Python does not have this distinctive Lispish feature.

Comment: `:.s/^/This site is not a discussion forum./ 
:wq!`

Answer (score -5):

Because Python can *also* program in a non-functional style, and that's not good enough for the FP purist.  More pragmatic coders, though, can enjoy the benefits of functional style without being dogmatic about it:

> “The functional programmer sounds
>   rather like a medieval monk, denying
>   himself the pleasures of life in the
>   hope that it will make him virtuous.
>   To those more interested in material
>   benefits, these “advantages” are not
>   very convincing. Functional
>   programmers argue that there are great
>   material benefits … [but] this is
>   plainly ridiculous. If omitting
>   assignment statements brought such
>   enormous benefits then FORTRAN
>   programmers would have been doing it
>   for twenty years. It is a logical
>   impossibility to make a language more
>   powerful by omitting features, no
>   matter how bad they may be.”

-- John Hughes, [Why functional programming matters](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.63.7911&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: As it stands, it seems like you are saying purer languages are merely a nicety.

Comment: @Mark C: Actually, what I was trying to say is that purer languages are a *nuisance,* at least if you're trying to actually get something useful done instead of forcing your coding style to conform to a specific dogma.

Comment: I agree. Any language without `goto` is terrible.

Comment: @Anon: Or its big sibling, `call-with-current-continuation`.

Comment: @Anon What about `COMEFROM`?

Comment: Mason, the paper you are citing is telling the exact opposite. Your citation is just a fragment of a couple of paragraphs of a paper that tells a different story. In fact, if you cited both paragraphs as a whole, they would clearly show another meaning.

Comment: @Marco: What do you mean? The author is explicitly saying that immutability and referential transparency aren't particularly useful, and the rest of the paper talks about how the true benefits of functional programming (according to Hughes) are modularization (the ability to break problems down into smaller pieces) and lazy evaluation.

Comment: @Mason: yes, the author claims modularization and lazy evaluation are the true benefits. But note how your original quote was out of context -- you seem to suggest the author is claiming something against FP, when in fact you quoted a paragraph from a paper with the conclusion that FP is great, just not for the misleading reason of "less is more". The title of the paper shows the intent of the author pretty clearly: "why functional programming matters" ;-) It certainly doesn't support your claim that the purer FP languanges "are a nuisance".

Comment: @Andrés F.: Fair enough, but bear in mind that this paper was written in 1984, before hybrid languages (such as Python) even existed.  The example imperative language he's comparing against is FORTRAN.  It wasn't possible to do any serious functional programming in languages that weren't specifically designed as functional languages.  That's not true today, and in that context it doesn't invalidate my original point.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: Hybrid languages predate Python by a loooooong stretch.  Lisp, for example, dates to 1959 and is, in fact, a multi-paradigm language.  It fully supports functional approaches, procedural approaches and object-oriented approaches to programming.  With the right macro packages on top you can also do logic programming pretty easily too.  Scheme, too, predates Python (and this paper).  It goes back to 1975.  Maybe you should take a glance at [this timeline of programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_programming_languages) sometime.

Comment: Lisp's OOP system existed before OOP became mainstream. The difference between Lisp and Python is, that Lisp is a multiparadigm language that makes FP easy, whereas in python it does feel awkward. I love python, but it is so full of state and changing state (`list.append()` et. al.).